# Is the Formatting Syntax of SimpleDateFormat a Java Invention?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-formatting

Is the syntax of date-time format strings as defined in Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class (like `"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"` and such) an original Java invention, or is it based on some other syntax definition like [ICU's](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax) or [CLDR's](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)?!

Is anybody aware of work that compares SimpleDateFormat syntax to those other definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.text.*`, introduced in JDK 1.1., was based on [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icufaq#TOC-How-does-ICU-relate-to-Java-s-java.text.-package-):

> ICU was originally developed by the Unicode group at the IBM
>   Globalization Center of Competency in Cupertino, and ICU was
>   contributed to Sun for inclusion into the JDK 1.1. ICU4J includes
>   enhanced versions of some of these contributed classes plus additional
>   classes that complement the classes in the JDK.

ICUs own [SimpleDateFormat](https://ssl.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) states that its symbols are based on "algorithm and pattern letters defined by UTS#35 Unicode Locale Data Markup Language (LDML)", which can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table).

Interestingly the Date-Pattern chapter was introduced into the Unicode Technical Report #35 in [Revision 3](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-3.html#Date_Format_Patterns) from 2004-10-27. 
Maybe ICU was then the original author?